# C# Bold a part of a string in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, string, richtextbox, bold

I am trying to bold the `"You >>"` part of this string to be displayed in a rich text box.

The following is my code for when the message send button is clicked. `displayBox` is where id like the string to be bold, `entryBox` is where the user is entering a message.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listData.Add(entryBox.Text);
        // Remove the linebreak caused by pressing return
        SendKeys.Send("\b");


        // Empty the array string
        ArrayData = "";

        // Bold the You >>
        displayBox.SelectionStart = 0;
        displayBox.SelectionLength = 6;
        displayBox.SelectionFont = new Font(displayBox.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        displayBox.SelectionLength = 0;

        foreach (string textItem in listData)
        {
            ArrayData = ArrayData + "You >> " + textItem + "\r\n";
        }
        entryBox.Focus();
        displayBox.Text = "";
        displayBox.Refresh();
        displayBox.Text = ArrayData;
        entryBox.Text = "";

    }
```

Any help would be great on this.

Comment: See http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/10/31/richtextbox-styles.aspx for worked examples. It looks like you are setting the formatting before adding the text - it should be the other way round (when there is something to select!)

Comment: Thanks for the link. You were correct, I was Setting the formatting before the actual string was being drawn into the richText box. The only issue Im having now is that only the first `"You >>"` Is being bolded. Any code pointers on how to implement this for every `"You >>"` ?

Comment: I have solved the issue with help from the link you posted. Thanks again @dash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue was solved with help from @dash's link in the comments.
Link: http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/10/31/richtextbox-styles.aspx

This is my code as It stands now for the same button (although I have renamed it since). This may not be the cleanest solution to this issue but I achieved the desired result so I'm happy with it.
It is explained in the comments.

```
        private void send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (entryBox.Text != "")
        {
            listData.Add(entryBox.Text);
            // Remove the linebreak caused by pressing return
            SendKeys.Send("\b");

            // Empty the array string
            ArrayData = "";

            foreach (string textItem in listData)
            {
                ArrayData = ArrayData + "You >> " + textItem + "\r\n";
            }
            entryBox.Focus();
            displayBox.Text = "";
            displayBox.Refresh();
            displayBox.Text = ArrayData;

            // Format the "You >>"
            displayBox.SelectionStart = 0;
            displayBox.SelectionLength = 6;
            displayBox.SelectionFont = new Font(displayBox.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
            displayBox.SelectionColor = Color.Crimson;
            displayBox.SelectionLength = 0;
            string wordToFind = "You >>";
            int startIndex = 0;
            while (startIndex > -1)
            {
                startIndex = displayBox.Find(wordToFind, startIndex + 1,
                                displayBox.Text.Length,
                                RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
                if (startIndex > -1)
                {
                    displayBox.Select(startIndex, wordToFind.Length);
                    displayBox.SelectionFont = new Font(displayBox.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
                    displayBox.SelectionColor = Color.Crimson;
                }
            }
            // Reset the entry box to empty
            entryBox.Text = "";

        }
        // Remove the linebreak caused by pressing return
        SendKeys.Send("\b");
    }
```

I hope this provides anyone with a similar problem some help!

: Dan

Comment: +1 Good work. I usually pop back and add an answer when I leave a link in comments as it is very common for target links to disappear on the net as sites close or move content around. You have saved this for posterity here on SO. There are few things more frustrating than, "The answer is just in this link", click, Page Not Found!

Comment: Thanks @dash. I know exactly what you mean!

Answer (score 1):

Try this : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37668/Multiple-Colored-Texts-in-RichTextBox-using-C

or this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15038/C-Formatting-Text-in-a-RichTextBox-by-Parsing-the

I think i used one, dont remember which, but i had success.

Comment: Thanks @Wish but I have the issue resolved already. Ill give the links a look over anyways. Id like to become more familiar with this kind of stuff.