# C# Rich Text Box Bold

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I am trying to implement a RichTextBox which displays certain words with formatting. The Box is to be used for a newsfeed so things such as the title of the news should be bold (and other words of interest bold also).

Currently, I have used

```
TextBox1.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi This is in \b bold\b0.}";
```

As provided by microsoft. This works. However, when I use:

```
TextBox1.RTF = @"{{rtf1\ansi" + my news + "}";
```

The news appears without line breaks.

To explain my situation, my app gets the news from a remote Database. I want to be able to specify what things appear in bold etc from the Database. eg:

[B]Title[/B]
Here is some random news so take [i]note of this[/i] and [b]this too[/b]

As an example. How would be the best way to include formatting remotely to my application?

thanks

Comment: Duplicate Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383772/c-sharp-bold-a-part-of-a-string-in-a-richtextbox

Comment: Also, for the carriage return issue, take a look a the [MultiLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.multiline.aspx) property

Comment: @Gus: The multi-line property is set to True

Comment: @Shaharyar: I've read that. However, how would I implement that so that I change formatting on my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just doing some very simple formatting (not nested or anything) you can just markup your original text and replace your markup with RTF control characters. For instance, the sample below uses HTML to markup the text and swaps out the `<strong>` and `<br />` tags for `{\b }` and `{\line}` groups:

```
var my_news = "<strong>This is my title</strong><br />And this is my text";
my_news = my_news.Replace("<strong>", @"{\b ").Replace("</strong>", "}").Replace("<br />", @"{\line}");
richTextBox1.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi " + my_news + "}";
```